# Full Drupal migrate from 7 to 10, site using CiviCRM

Tags: migration

I manage a website based on Drupal 7 where we use CiviCRM

I would like to migrate to Drupal 10, but I have a lot of doubts about this procedure...

Can you recommend any materials that reliably describe and help in such a process, courses, training or instructions?

Answer (score 1):

Civi by itself doesn't care too much if it's drupal 7 or 10.

You will need php 8.1+. Some extensions may not be ready yet for php 8.1, but by now most should be ok.

Most of what you need to address will be on the drupal side. Some of your existing drupal modules or themes may not work with drupal 10, or will have a different module as a replacement.

You will need to manually recreate any drupal views or webforms.

Comment: If you are using the same db for drupal and civicrm, then you'll have to copy the civicrm tables over separately to the new db - the drupal migrate won't (normally) know anything about those tables. Generally what I'd recommend is to ignore civicrm and first just sort out your migration to Drupal without CiviCRM. Then install civicrm on your new drupal (installation of civicrm is quite different, now using composer), and then update your civicrm tables with your backed up tables from your old site.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Views and webforms ar our biggest consideration, we have sometimes 50+ webforms and lot of views with diffrent settings

Comment: We have done a lot of work over the years to try and improve the migration of civi related Views and Webforms. They still hit issues and require some manual rebuilding but it is much better imo than manually building them from scratch. For webform look for https://github.com/fuzionnz/webform_civicrm_migrate but note that it is a WIP. We have a patch as well that we have used to help with Views migrations but I don't know off-hand if it is still necessary/useful (and dev who made it is off till later this month)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Drupal website or any of the integrations with Drupal?  If not, and it is just a container to run Civi then consider switching to WordPress - many small orgs find that easier than Drupal 10.

Comment: Thanks but we run over 30 sites using Drupal and moving to WP is not an option :-)

Comment: Do all 30 sites also involve CiviCRM?

Comment: Yes, all sites are with CiviCRM